# Use greenscreen as holdout

Tags: transparency, chromakey

I'm trying to do an effect where I have 3d objects in a vortex around a person in a shot (like [this](https://youtu.be/TqUT3BevAys?t=31))

Basically, right now I have the shot pre-keyed in a png sequence and I'm using the alpha from the sequence on an image plane. This makes it so when the objects pass behind the person, they're hidden from view.

[image]

The problem is that it leaves a gray image where the key was and I can't figure out how to make this transparent as well (I'm trying to just drop the render result from blender into a comp to complete the effect)

Holdout doesn't work because it's a plane, and it holds out the entire plane instead of just where the alpha is

EDIT: I found a workaround by changing the gray color of the image to green and then keying it out. The edges are a little rough, but it gets the job done.

Comment: You can use holdout shader mix with your setup and use alpha as mix factor.

Comment: not a complete solution, but i'm curious what happens when you increase the transmission on the principled shader to 1

Comment: Can you connect the alpha of the image with the surface of the output node and show us what happens?

Comment: @PavanBhadaja you're a mad genius, it freaking worked